# vb.net populate multicolumn listview

Tags: vb.net, listview, multiple-columns

I'm a very newbie with VB.NET so excuse me for silly question.
I have a two-dimensional array and want populate listview with it's elements. For this I'm trying use something like this:

```
lst_arrayShow.Items.Clear()
    For currentColumn As Integer = 0 To (columnsCnt - 1)
        lst_arrayShow.Columns.Add("")
        For currentRow As Integer = 0 To (rowsCnt - 1)
            'lst_arrayShow.Items.Add()
        Next
    Next
```

What should I use instead of `'lst_arrayShow.Items.Add()` ? 
**UPD:** columnsCnt is number of columns in array and rowsCnt is number of rows in array

Comment: what is `columnsCnt`?  One of the array sizes or based on the listview?  Your loop will be more complex because you need to create a ListViewItem then add SubItems to it.  The LV is not a grid and does not have columns, but the SubItems are displayed as columns.

Comment: Sorry. Yes, columnsCnt is number of columns in array and rowsCnt is number of rows in array

Comment: then just loop on RowsCount to add that many LVIs, and each if them has 1 SubItem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a multicolumn `ListView` you need to set the property `View` to `View.Details` and then be sure to define all the columns needed. So, if you haven't already done it in the Designer, you need to add the columns required to your `ListView`

```
lst_arrayShow.View = View.Details
For currentColumn As Integer = 0 To (columnsCnt - 1)
    lst_arrayShow.Columns.Add("Column Nr: " & currentColumn
Next
```

Next, now that you have defined the columns, you could loop over your rows and create a `ListViewItem` for each row.
The `ListViewItem` has a `Subitems` collection that correspond to the Columns defined above

```
For currentRow As Integer = 0 To (rowsCnt - 1)

    ' Create the ListViewItem with the value from the first column
    Dim item = new ListViewItem(yourArray(currentRow,0))
    
    ' The remainder columns after the first are added to the SubItems collection
    For currentColumn As Integer = 1 To (columnsCnt - 1)
         item.SubItems.Add(yourArray(currentRow,currentColumn))
    Next
    
    ' Finally, the whole ListViewItem is added to the ListView
    lst_arrayShow.Items.Add(item)
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! It's almost what I need, but in listview only one row is shown.

Comment: In which order do you have your rows and columns inside your array?. This code assumes: the first dimension of the array are rows.

Comment: Nothing wrong was with an array and your code. I just didn't set `View` property. If I add `lst_arrayShow.View = View.Details` all works great. Thanks for your advices!

Comment: Ahh, I thought you had already done in the designer. I will add this to complete the answer.

Answer (score 4):

This should add items in three columns in one row:

```
lst_arrayShow.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(New String() {"Item in column 1", "Item in column 2", "Item in column 3"}))
```

You could add additional items to other columns by just continuing to add strings `{<string for column 1>, <string for column 2>, <... column 3>, <... column 4>, <... column 5>}`.